# Test expected exceptions in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, testing, exception, junit4

In Java, the programmer can specify expected exceptions for JUnit test cases like this:

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)
public void omg()
{
    int blackHole = 1 / 0;
}
```

How would I do this in Kotlin? I have tried two syntax variations, but none of them worked:

```
import org.junit.Test

// ...

@Test(expected = ArithmeticException) fun omg()
    Please specify constructor invocation;
    classifier 'ArithmeticException' does not have a companion object

@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class) fun omg()
                            name expected ^
                                            ^ expected ')'
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

The Kotlin translation of the Java example for **JUnit 4.12** is:

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException::class)
fun omg() {
    val blackHole = 1 / 0
}
```

However, **JUnit 4.13** [introduced](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/HEAD/doc/ReleaseNotes4.13.md) two `assertThrows` methods for finer-granular exception scopes:

```
@Test
fun omg() {
    // ...
    assertThrows(ArithmeticException::class.java) {
        val blackHole = 1 / 0
    }
    // ...
}
```

Both `assertThrows` methods return the expected exception for additional assertions:

```
@Test
fun omg() {
    // ...
    val exception = assertThrows(ArithmeticException::class.java) {
        val blackHole = 1 / 0
    }
    assertEquals("/ by zero", exception.message)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 125):

[Kotlin has its own test helper package](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/kotlin.test) that can help to do this kind of unittest.

Your test can be very expressive by use `assertFailWith`:

```
@Test
fun test_arithmethic() {
    assertFailsWith<ArithmeticException> {
        omg()
    }
}
```

Comment: If get a 404 on your link, has `kotlin.test` been replaced by something else?

Comment: @fredoverflow No, is not replaced, but just removed from standard libraries. I've updated link to github kotlin repository but unfortunately I cannot find any link to documentation. Anyway jar is shipped by kotlin-plugin in intelliJ or you can find it on the net or add maven/grandle dependency to your project.

Comment: compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"

Comment: @mac229 s/compile/testCompile/

Comment: @AshishSharma : https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-fails-with.html assertFailWith return the exception and you can use it to write your own assert.

Comment: I manage to that like below. But If anybody can provide me an example how can i check for exception type in case of completablefutue because it wrapped actual exception class .   var exception =  assertFailsWith(CustomException::class) {
            someclass.somemethod(arg)
        }
        Assertions.assertEquals("some message", exception.localizedMessage)

Answer (score 29):

You can use `@Test(expected = ArithmeticException::class)` or even better one of Kotlin's library methods like [`failsWith()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.test/fails-with.html).

You can make it even shorter by using reified generics and a helper method like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Throwable> failsWithX(noinline block: () -> Any) {
    kotlin.test.failsWith(javaClass<T>(), block)
}
```

And example using the annotation:

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException::class)
fun omg() {

}
```

Comment: `javaClass<T>()` is deprecated now.
Use `MyException::class.java` instead.

Comment: failsWith is deprecated, [assertFailsWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.test/assert-fails-with.html) should be used instead.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [Kotest](https://github.com/kotest/kotest) for this.

In your test, you can wrap arbitrary code with a shouldThrow block:

```
shouldThrow<ArithmeticException> {
  // code in here that you expect to throw a ArithmeticException
}
```

Comment: seems line it doesn't work in proper way.

I check 
1. shouldThrow<java.lang.AssertionError> { someMethod().isOK shouldBe true } - green
2. shouldThrow<java.lang.AssertionError> { someMethod().isOK shouldBe false } - green 

someMethod() throw "java.lang.AssertionError: message" when it should, and return object if OK. 

In both cases  shouldThrow is green when OK and when NOT.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the docs, it might have changed since my answer in 2016. https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#exceptions

Answer (score 19):

JUnit5 has [kotlin support](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions-kotlin) built in.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertThrows

class MyTests {
    @Test
    fun `division by zero -- should throw ArithmeticException`() {
        assertThrows<ArithmeticException> {  1 / 0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my preferred answer. If you get `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6` on assertThrows, make sure your build.gradle has `compileTestKotlin {
  kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}`

Answer (score 16):

You can also use generics with kotlin.test package:

```
import kotlin.test.assertFailsWith 

@Test
fun testFunction() {
    assertFailsWith<MyException> {
         // The code that will throw MyException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nobody mentioned that assertFailsWith() returns the value and you can check exception attributes:

```
@Test
fun `my test`() {
        val exception = assertFailsWith<MyException> {method()}
        assertThat(exception.message, equalTo("oops!"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This simple sample worked in the 4.13.2 version of Junit

```
    @Test
    fun testZeroDividing(){
        var throwing = ThrowingRunnable {  /*call your method here*/ Calculator().divide(1,0) }
        assertThrows(/*define your exception here*/ IllegalArgumentException::class.java, throwing)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assert extension that verifies the exception class and also if the error message match.

```
inline fun <reified T : Exception> assertThrows(runnable: () -> Any?, message: String?) {
   try {
       runnable.invoke()
   } catch (e: Throwable) {
       if (e is T) {
           message?.let {
               Assert.assertEquals(it, "${e.message}")
           }
        return
       }
       Assert.fail("expected ${T::class.qualifiedName} but caught " +
            "${e::class.qualifiedName} instead")
   }

   Assert.fail("expected ${T::class.qualifiedName}")
}
```

for example:

```
assertThrows<IllegalStateException>({
        throw IllegalStateException("fake error message")
    }, "fake error message")
```

Answer (score 2):

### org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.kt

````
/**
 * Example usage:
 * ```kotlin
 * val exception = assertThrows<IllegalArgumentException>("Should throw an Exception") {
 *     throw IllegalArgumentException("Talk to a duck")
 * }
 * assertEquals("Talk to a duck", exception.message)
 * ```
 * @see Assertions.assertThrows
 */
inline fun <reified T : Throwable> assertThrows(message: String, noinline executable: () -> Unit): T =
        assertThrows({ message }, executable)
````

Answer (score 0):

Another version of syntaxis using [kluent](https://github.com/MarkusAmshove/Kluent):

```
@Test
fun `should throw ArithmeticException`() {
    invoking {
        val backHole = 1 / 0
    } `should throw` ArithmeticException::class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firt steps is to add `(expected = YourException::class)` in test annotation

```
@Test(expected = YourException::class)
```

Second step is to add this function

```
private fun throwException(): Boolean = throw YourException()
```

Finally you will have something like this:

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException::class)
fun `get query error from assets`() {
    //Given
    val error = "ArithmeticException"

    //When
    throwException()
    val result =  omg()

    //Then
    Assert.assertEquals(result, error)
}
private fun throwException(): Boolean = throw ArithmeticException()
```