# Kotlin and JUnit 5 assert an exception is thrown: separate declaration and execution with assertFailsWith

Tags: exception, kotlin, lambda, junit5, assertion

In Kotlin with JUnit5 we can use [assertFailsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331806/test-expected-exceptions-in-kotlin)

In Java with JUnit5 you can use [assertThrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268446/junit-5-how-to-assert-an-exception-is-thrown)

In Java, if I want to **separate the declaration of an executable from the execution itself**, in order to clarify the tests in a Given-Then-When form, we can use JUnit5 `assertThrows` like this:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("display() with wrong argument command should fail" )
void displayWithWrongArgument() {

    // Given a wrong argument
    String arg = "FAKE_ID"

    // When we call display() with the wrong argument
    Executable exec = () -> sut.display(arg);

    // Then it should throw an IllegalArgumentException
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, exec);
}
```

In Kotlin we can use `assertFailsWith`:

```
@Test
fun `display() with wrong argument command should fail`() {

    // Given a wrong argument
    val arg = "FAKE_ID"

    // When we call display() with the wrong argument
    // ***executable declaration should go here ***

    // Then it should throw an IllegalArgumentException
    assertFailsWith<CrudException> { sut.display(arg) }
}
```

But, **how we can separate the declaration and the execution in Kotlin with `assertFailsWith`?**

Comment: JUnit 5 has Kotlin support for built-in assertions - see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions-kotlin

Answer (score 11):

Just declare a variable like you did in Java:

```
@Test
fun `display() with wrong argument command should fail`() {

    // Given a wrong argument
    val arg = "FAKE_ID"

    // When we call display() with the wrong argument
    val block: () -> Unit = { sut.display(arg) }

    // Then it should throw an IllegalArgumentException
    assertFailsWith<CrudException>(block = block)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

in my example you can do like this :

```
@Test
fun divide() {
    assertThrows(
        ArithmeticException::class.java,
        { MathUtils.divide(1, 0) },
        "divide by zero should trow"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really agree with p3quod's claim on the Given/When/Then (or Arrange/Act/Assert) pattern.

My way in Kotlin:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable

@Test
fun `display() with wrong argument command should fail`() {

    // Given a wrong argument
    val arg = "FAKE_ID"

    // When we call display() with the wrong argument
    val executable = Executable { sut.display(arg) }

    // Then it should throw an IllegalArgumentException
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException::class.java, executable)
}
```

Is there a better way, more Kotlin like, let me know.