# junit4 Test Expected Exception

Tags: kotlin, junit

According to [Test expected exceptions in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331806/test-expected-exceptions-in-kotlin) I can use the @Test(expected=ExceptionClass) annotation to detect an exception.

```
@Test(expected = Exception::class)
fun `repo fails fetching top rated movies`() = runTest {
    val remoteDataSrc = mockk<MoviesRemoteDataSource>()
    val dispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
    val repository = MoviesRepository(remoteDataSrc, dispatcher)
    repository.movies = emptyList()

    coEvery { remoteDataSrc.getTopRatedMovies() } throws Exception()

    repository.getTopRatedMovies()
}
```

The above test fails with

> Expected exception: java.lang.Exception
> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.Exception

MoviesRepository

```
class MoviesRepository(
private val remoteDataSource: MoviesRemoteDataSource,
private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) {
var movies: List<Movie> = emptyList()

suspend fun getTopRatedMovies(): List<Movie> {
    if (movies.isNotEmpty()) return movies
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        try {
            movies = remoteDataSource.getTopRatedMovies().map { it.toDomain() }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }
    }
    return movies
  }
}
```

Comment: Your mainline code catches the exception you test as being thrown.

Comment: thanks im a moron for not noticing earelier